# Postgresql select from results in for loop like

Tags: database, postgresql, for-loop, select, recursion

My English isn't the best but I will try. I have tables with comments and replies, I am wanting to select parentids LIMIT 10 from comment and select the replies that are tied to those.

```
  parentid  |   replyid   |  commentowner  |         commentbody         |        postcreation        
------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------
 h0rfizsUF6 | CGTSh5XLCB  | mary@none.com  | anyone want to make flowers | 2018-04-30 21:35:53.502332
            | CGTSh5XLCB  | bob@none.com   | reply to mary about flowers | 2018-04-30 21:39:04.313967
            | CGTSh5XLCB  | mary@none.com  | ok well sign up             | 2018-04-30 21:39:33.376884
 Zasrw8768F | DAeing34355 | james@none.com | Hey everyone!               | 2018-04-30 21:40:44.777557
 Zasr2222F  | DAeingrrrr  | mary@none.com  | yo yo yo all                | 2018-04-30 21:41:33.800034
            | CGTSh5XLCB  | james@none.com | Im signed up already        | 2018-04-30 21:42:03.771954
            | DAeingrrrr  | jimmy@none.com | in what house               | 2018-04-30 21:43:10.992619
(7 rows)
```

What I want:

```
  parentid  |   replyid   |  commentowner  |         commentbody         |        postcreation        
------------+-------------+----------------+-----------------------------+----------------------------
 h0rfizsUF6 | CGTSh5XLCB  | mary@none.com  | anyone want to make flowers | 2018-04-30 21:35:53.502332
            | CGTSh5XLCB  | bob@none.com   | reply to mary about flowers | 2018-04-30 21:39:04.313967
            | CGTSh5XLCB  | mary@none.com  | ok well sign up             | 2018-04-30 21:39:33.376884
            | CGTSh5XLCB  | james@none.com | Im signed up already        | 2018-04-30 21:42:03.771954
 Zasr2222F  | DAeingrrrr  | mary@none.com  | yo yo yo all                | 2018-04-30 21:41:33.800034
            | DAeingrrrr  | jimmy@none.com | in what house               | 2018-04-30 21:43:10.992619
```

when I get the parentids I am returned with this

```
socialnetwork=# select parentid from comments where commentowner ='mary@none.com' and parentid IS NOT NULL;
  parentid  
------------
 h0rfizsUF6
 Zasr2222F
```

but I cannot perform a forloop through this return.

```
ERROR:  more than one row returned by a subquery used as an expression
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not entirely clear what you're trying to do, but perhaps
something like the following:

```
with parents as (
    select distinct replyid
    from comments
    where commentowner ='mary@none.com' and parentid IS NOT NULL
)
select C.* from parents P left join comments C on P.replyid = C.replyid
;
```

This aren't ten parentids, but your example table has nulls in the parentid column, and it's not clear how the rows are associated together.
The identical replyid columns are confusing as well.  Perhaps those should be parentid, or commentid.

In any case, you can use a CTE to construct the set of keys you're interested in, and then join against the table to get the rows you want.

Comment: The replyis from the parent is what ties them together. The parentid identifies a sort of topic. This way the parent can identify it's children.  Let me try it out.

Comment: Ok this was pretty close . It set me on the right path . Your select did everything corect except for the order was off somewhat. This seems to fix it completely. :::

 with parents as (select distinct replyid from comments where commentowner ='mary@none.com' and parentid IS NOT NULL) select C.* from parents P left join comments C on P.replyid = C.replyid order by replyid,postcreation;